# Error in mapping with automapper even though classes are configured

Tags: c#, automapper

I have these classes to map
NFeMovementInsertPayload → NFeMovement
All child classes will also be mapped.

Origin

```
public class NFeMovementInsertPayload : NFeMovementBaseCrudPayload
    {
        public NFeMovementInsertPayload()
        {
            Items = new();
            Fiscal = new();
        }

        public List<NFeItemInsertPayload> Items { get; set; }
        public NotaFiscalInsertPayload Fiscal { get; set; }
    }
```

Destiny

```
public class NFeMovement
{
    private int id;

    public NFeMovement()
    {
        Fiscal = new NotaFiscal();
        Transport = new MovementTransport();
        Items = new List<NFeMovementItem>(990);
        Issuer = new FiscalMovementIssuer();
        OriginLinkMovement = new MovementLink();
    }

    public decimal? OtherValue { get; set; }
    public decimal NetTotal { get; set; }
    public int RecipientId { get; set; }
    public int PriceListId { get; set; }
    public decimal QuantityItems { get; set; }
    public decimal? ShippingCost { get; set; }
    public FiscalNFeStatus StatusId { get; set; }
    public FiscalMovementType TypeId { get; set; }
    public NotaFiscal Fiscal { get; set; }
    public MovementTransport Transport { get; set; }
    public List<NFeMovementItem> Items { get; set; }
    public FiscalMovementIssuer Issuer { get; set; }
    public MovementLink OriginLinkMovement { get; set; }
}
```

Configured mappings

```
//payloads
CreateMap<NFeMovementInsertPayload, NFeMovement>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.GrossTotal,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(orig => orig.Items.Sum(x => x.Subtotal)))
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.QuantityItems,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(orig => orig.Items.Sum(x => x.Quantity)));
CreateMap<NFeItemInsertPayload, NFeMovementItem>();
CreateMap<NotaFiscalInsertPayload, NotaFiscal>();
CreateMap<PagamentoNFeInsertPayload, PagamentoNFe>();
```

Even having all classes mapped I get this error

```
Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
NFeMovementInsertPayload -> NFeMovement
LogSistemas.Domynus.Application.Core.Payload.Fiscal.NFeMovementInsertPayload -> LogSistemas.Domynus.Application.Core.Entities.Fiscal.NFeMovement

Type Map configuration:
NFeMovementInsertPayload -> NFeMovement
LogSistemas.Domynus.Application.Core.Payload.Fiscal.NFeMovementInsertPayload -> LogSistemas.Domynus.Application.Core.Entities.Fiscal.NFeMovement

Destination Member:
Fiscal
```

The classes in mapping error are configured.

Classes mentioned in mapping error:

```
public class NFeMovementInsertPayload : NFeMovementBaseCrudPayload
{
    public NFeMovementInsertPayload()
    {
        Items = new();
        Fiscal = new();
    }

    public List<NFeItemInsertPayload> Items { get; set; }
    public NotaFiscalInsertPayload Fiscal { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class NotaFiscal
{
    public NotaFiscal()
    {
        InfNFe = new InfNFe();
        Identificacao = new IdentificacaoNFe();
        Emitente = new EmitenteNFe();
        Destinatario = new DestinatarioNFe();
        AutXML = new List<AutXML>(10);
        Total = new TotalNFe();
        Transportador = new TransportadorNFe();
        Pagamentos = new List<PagamentoNFe>();
        DadosAdicionais = new DadosAdicionaisNFe();
        InfRespTec = new InfRespTec();
        Eventos = new List<ProtEventoNFe>();

        InfNFe.Versao = "4.00";
    }


    public InfNFe InfNFe { get; set; }
    public IdentificacaoNFe Identificacao { get; set; }
    public EmitenteNFe Emitente { get; set; }
    public DestinatarioNFe Destinatario { get; set; }
    public List<AutXML> AutXML { get; set; }
    public TotalNFe Total { get; set; }
    public TransportadorNFe Transportador { get; set; }
    public List<PagamentoNFe> Pagamentos { get; set; }
    public DadosAdicionaisNFe DadosAdicionais { get; set; }
    public InfRespTec InfRespTec { get; set; }
    public List<ProtEventoNFe> Eventos { get; set; }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I have no idea

Tried configuring ForMember but didnt work

Comment: I think this might be an error in Mapping the `NotaFiscalInsertPayload` to `NotaFiscal`? Can you share the `NotaFiscalInsertPayload` class? As I could see the `NotaFiscal` has lots of User Defined Type, you have to have the mapping for those too, for a successful mapping unless those members are of same types in both the classes.

Comment: @SathishGuruV you are right. I had found and its exactly what you said.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

it was missing the map for class `DestinatarioNFeCrudPayload`.

I made a mapper.Map() just for `NotaFiscalInsertPayload` and i got the error informing the field `Destinatario`.

Must have mapped all Types.